# Value direction change in a pandas column

Tags: pandas

I have a column in a dataframe like below

```html
Difference
0
0
0.067
0
0
0
0
0.062
0
0
0
0
0.018
0
0
0
0
-0.085
0
0
0
0
0.033
0
0
0
0
0.034
0
0
0
0
-0.083
0
0
0
0
-0.226
0
0
0
0
0.192
0
0
0
0
0.175
0
0
0
0
0.069
0
0
0
0
-0.066
0
0
```

The values can be a few continuous negative & a few continuous positives.
I want to add a column which has the sum of continuous positives & continuous negatives (column="Switch" in the result example), the a column which shows the difference in values(column="Switch Value" in the result example) & finally, if two values in "Switch" column are positive, then "True" in another column ((column="Same Switch" in the result example). The expected result is as below.

```html
Difference Switch Switch Value Same Switch
0   
0   
0.067   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0.062   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0.018   
0   
0   
0   
0   
-0.085 0.147  
0   
0   
0   
0   
0.033 -0.085 0.232 False
0   
0   
0   
0   
0.034   
0   
0   
0   
0   
-0.083 0.067 -0.152 False
0   
0   
0   
0   
-0.226   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0.192 -0.309 0.376 False
0   
0   
0   
0   
0.175   
0   
0   
0   
0   
0.069 0.436 -0.745 False
0   
0   
0   
0   
-0.066 0.003 0.433 True
0   
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
m = df['Difference'].ne(0)
posneg =  df['Difference'].where(m).ffill().gt(0)
g = posneg.ne(posneg.shift()).cumsum()
g = g.mask(df['Difference'].eq(0).groupby(g).transform('all')).bfill()

df['Switch'] = np.where(~g.duplicated(), df['Difference'].groupby(g).transform('sum').shift(), np.nan)
df['Switch Value'] = np.where(~g.duplicated(), df['Switch'].ffill().shift().diff(-1), np.nan)
mask = df['Switch Value'].notna()
df['Same Switch'] = df.loc[mask, 'Switch'].eq(df.loc[mask, 'Switch Value'])
```

---

```
print (df.head(30))
    Difference  Switch  Switch Value Same Switch
0        0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
1        0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
2        0.067     NaN           NaN         NaN
3        0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
4        0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
5        0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
6        0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
7        0.062     NaN           NaN         NaN
8        0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
9        0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
10       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
11       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
12       0.018     NaN           NaN         NaN
13       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
14       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
15       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
16       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
17      -0.085   0.147           NaN         NaN
18       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
19       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
20       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
21       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
22       0.033  -0.085         0.232       False
23       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
24       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
25       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
26       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
27       0.034     NaN           NaN         NaN
28       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
29       0.000     NaN           NaN         NaN
```

Comment: is there a way i can do this after groupby? "Switch",  "Switch Value" & "Same Switch" for each group.

Comment: @mohanys - Not so easy, I think the best is create new question.

Comment: ok. new question created [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786932/value-direction-change-in-a-pandas-column-after-groupby]