# sum & count not working properly after groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below (actual dataframe is very big, showing just a snippet here)

```html
Cycle Type Time Values
2 2 101 20.402
2 2 102 20.402
2 2 103 20.502
2 2 104 20.402
2 2 105 20.802
2 2 106 20.383
2 2 107 20.383
2 2 108 20.282
2 2 109 20.38
3 1 101 20.402
3 1 102 20.402
3 1 103 20.502
3 1 104 20.402
3 1 105 20.802
3 1 106 20.383
3 1 107 20.383
3 1 108 20.282
3 1 109 20.38
5 3 101 20.402
5 3 102 20.402
5 3 103 20.502
5 3 104 20.402
5 3 105 20.802
5 3 106 20.383
5 3 107 20.383
5 3 108 20.282
5 3 109 20.38
```

I wanted to  find the continuous negative & positive values within each group (I group by 'Cycle' & 'Type') & the number of steps take for that value.
So, based on the answer to an earlier question (link --> [Value direction change in a pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56730036/value-direction-change-in-a-pandas-column)),
I put the code as below

```
`data_train['Detrended'] = data_train.groupby(['Cycle','Type']).Values.diff()

mtest_bel = data_train.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Values'].diff().ne(0)
posnegtest_bel =  (data_train.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Detrended']).apply(lambda x: x.where(mtest_bel).ffill().gt(0))
gtest_bel = posnegtest_bel.ne(posnegtest_bel.shift()).cumsum()
gtest_bel = gtest_bel.mask(data_train.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Detrended'].apply(lambda x: x.eq(0).groupby(gtest_bel).transform('all')).bfill())
data_train['SwitchCount'] = (np.where(~gtest_bel.duplicated(), 
                                          data_train.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Detrended']
                                          .apply(lambda x: x.groupby(gtest_bel).transform('count')), np.nan))
data_train['Switch'] = (np.where(~gtest_bel.duplicated(), data_train.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Detrended']
                                     .apply(lambda x: x.groupby(gtest_bel).transform('sum')), np.nan))
```

`
It seems to work for few groups but not for others

If it works properly, the first row of every group should have values in column "SwitchCount" and "Switch". But as you can see in the pictures , that is not happening. We have values for "SwitchCount" and "Switch" in the first row for some groups but not others. Can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong?
[image]

if I take the group value separately & use the formula, it works!
Below is the picture of group Cycle=7 & Type =2 which is taken as separate df & in that i first row shows the values for "SwitchCount" and "Switch"!!!
[image]

**Update** Pictures below are added after suggestion from  one of the contributors (jezrael) to create new column for each Series for better debug. It appears that if the last value of the previous group is of the same symbol of new value of the new group (negative or positive) this issue occurs.
But my code is on the groupby object, so I assumed it should start over. I am still not able to solve this.
[image]

Comment: Is possible share more data? e.g. in file?

Comment: Not easy find problem for me, because your test data cannot be tested by me, because I have no input file. So it is reason for share it (or change input data with groups with problematic output and also then best previous and next groups too), because here seems some data related problem.

Comment: The csv file with the data is in the link [http://www.sharecsv.com/s/1f3b09e6234cac5842f1f35fb9f87752/Training.csv] you can ignore the 'EndTime' column.

Comment: Can you test if change `~data_train['gtest_bel1'].duplicated()` to `~data_train.duplicated(['gtest_bel1','Cycle','Type'])`  it working?

Comment: This works but how to get the same on the original code? In that code, we did not "gtest_bel" as a column in the data frame. it was just a series we used.

Comment: give me some time, please.

Comment: Sorry if my message came across as pushing you for a quick answer. That was not my intention. I just posted the outcome of you suggestion. Take your time. You have already been very helpful.

Comment: No problem, use `data_train[['Cycle','Type']].assign(a=gtest_bel).duplicated()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

After some debug problem is with test duplicates, need test per 3 columns, not only by one.

So is necessary change:

```
~gtest_bel.duplicated()
```

to:

```
~data_train[['Cycle','Type']].assign(a=gtest_bel).duplicated()
```

for test in all 3 columns of helper `DataFrame`.

---

I suggest create new column for each `Series` for better debug:

```
data_train['Detrended'] = data_train.groupby(['Cycle','Type']).Values.diff()
data_train['mtest_bel'] = data_train['Detrended'].ne(0)
data_train['posnegtest_bel'] =  (data_train.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Detrended']).apply(lambda x: x.where(data_train['mtest_bel']).ffill().gt(0))
data_train['gtest_bel'] = data_train['posnegtest_bel'].ne(data_train['posnegtest_bel'].shift()).cumsum()


data_train['gtest_bel1'] = data_train['gtest_bel'].mask(data_train.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Detrended'].apply(lambda x: x.eq(0).groupby(data_train['gtest_bel']).transform('all')).bfill())
data_train['SwitchCount'] = (np.where(~data_train['gtest_bel1'].duplicated(), 
                                     data_train.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Detrended']
                                              .apply(lambda x: x.groupby(data_train['gtest_bel1']).transform('count')), np.nan))
data_train['Switch'] = (np.where(~data_train['gtest_bel1'].duplicated(), data_train.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Detrended']
                                     .apply(lambda x: x.groupby(data_train['gtest_bel1']).transform('sum')), np.nan))
```

---

```
#only for better seen groups, after debug remove next row
data_train = data_train.set_index(['Cycle','Type'])
print (data_train)
            Time  Values  Detrended  mtest_bel  posnegtest_bel  gtest_bel  \
Cycle Type                                                                  
2     2      101  20.402        NaN       True           False          1   
      2      102  20.402      0.000      False           False          1   
      2      103  20.502      0.100       True            True          2   
      2      104  20.402     -0.100       True           False          3   
      2      105  20.802      0.400       True            True          4   
      2      106  20.383     -0.419       True           False          5   
      2      107  20.383      0.000      False           False          5   
      2      108  20.282     -0.101       True           False          5   
      2      109  20.380      0.098       True            True          6   
3     1      101  20.402        NaN       True           False          7   
      1      102  20.402      0.000      False           False          7   
      1      103  20.502      0.100       True            True          8   
      1      104  20.402     -0.100       True           False          9   
      1      105  20.802      0.400       True            True         10   
      1      106  20.383     -0.419       True           False         11   
      1      107  20.383      0.000      False           False         11   
      1      108  20.282     -0.101       True           False         11   
      1      109  20.380      0.098       True            True         12   
5     3      101  20.402        NaN       True           False         13   
      3      102  20.402      0.000      False           False         13   
      3      103  20.502      0.100       True            True         14   
      3      104  20.402     -0.100       True           False         15   
      3      105  20.802      0.400       True            True         16   
      3      106  20.383     -0.419       True           False         17   
      3      107  20.383      0.000      False           False         17   
      3      108  20.282     -0.101       True           False         17   
      3      109  20.380      0.098       True            True         18   

            gtest_bel1  SwitchCount  Switch  
Cycle Type                                   
2     2              1          1.0   0.000  
      2              1          NaN     NaN  
      2              2          1.0   0.100  
      2              3          1.0  -0.100  
      2              4          1.0   0.400  
      2              5          3.0  -0.520  
      2              5          NaN     NaN  
      2              5          NaN     NaN  
      2              6          1.0   0.098  
3     1              7          1.0   0.000  
      1              7          NaN     NaN  
      1              8          1.0   0.100  
      1              9          1.0  -0.100  
      1             10          1.0   0.400  
      1             11          3.0  -0.520  
      1             11          NaN     NaN  
      1             11          NaN     NaN  
      1             12          1.0   0.098  
5     3             13          1.0   0.000  
      3             13          NaN     NaN  
      3             14          1.0   0.100  
      3             15          1.0  -0.100  
      3             16          1.0   0.400  
      3             17          3.0  -0.520  
      3             17          NaN     NaN  
      3             17          NaN     NaN  
      3             18          1.0   0.098
```

Comment: I have done as you said. The picture has been added to the original post as an update. I know the problem now but not able to find the solution. Stopping "posnegtest_bel", "gtest_bel" & "gtest_bel1"at the end of each group & starting over again from 1 in the new group would probably solve this. However, i am not able to figure how.